# Look down upon vs look down on

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I have searched the meaning of **look down upon** as well as **look down on** is 'to hate' or  to consider someone or something lesser or inferior in some way.

But when we use **look down upon** and **look down on**?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless it's meant *literally*, of course. In which case the meaning has nothing to do with emotion or belief—but only to do with physical action and vision.

Comment: I'd say the slight difference would be you'd look on a single item, and upon 'the entire set' - you'd look (down) on a man, but upon a nation, on the boss but upon the firm. But they are mostly interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search should have included one or two good dictionaries. The only difference between those two phrases is that "upon" is slightly more formal, and is more likely to be found in British English, than "on".

[Upon (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/upon)

"Hate" is an inaccurate description of the meaning of "look down on/upon". The phrase, when used figuratively, simply means "to think that you are better than somebody/something".

[Look down on (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/look-down-on?q=look%20down%20on)